# Are edited files in core modules overwritten on updating Drupal?

Tags: 8, users

I have searched related questions but could't really find a decisive YES or NO.

I changed a few files in core/modules/user/ ... to alter the display of the form used on my site. For example:

```
 $form['account']['name'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Username'),
      '#maxlength' => USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH,
      '#description' => $this->t(''),
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => ['username'],
        'placeholder' => $this->t('Username'),   // ADDED THIS
        'autocorrect' => 'off',
        'autocapitalize' => 'off',
        'spellcheck' => 'false',
      ],
      '#default_value' => (!$register ? $account->getAccountName() : ''),
      '#access' => ($register || ($user->id() == $account->id() && $user->hasPermission('change own username')) || $admin),
    ];
```

> Do these edited core files revert back to their original state thus deleting my changes when I update Drupal in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES, for sure. Clear enough ....?

PS: that's also why one should never hack core ...

Comment: Unless you use composer and composer patches, technically.. but otherwise no.

Comment: Why not use a form alter hook?

Comment: Thank you, that's very clear indeed. How can I alter this form then? @4k4 suggest a form alter hook, where do I place this?

Comment: In a custom module, in a custom theme..